# Install Node v8 and v14 in one machine using Homebrew

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew, nvm

I am using **macOS Catalina 10.15.5**, **Homebrew 2.4.12** and now I have installed **Node v14.8.0** and **Nvm 0.35.3**.

all of this was installed by **Homebrew** (`node` and `nvm` are installed formulae).

My goal is:

- install version 8 of **Node** without uninstalling the existing one
- have ability to switch between versions easily (8 and 14)

As I saw some time ago, in **Homebrew** repository there was available formula `node@8`, but now it isn't.

Should I tap additional repo to check out `node@8` formula?
If it is totally unavailable for brew, is it ok to use `nvm` formula to manage versions? if yes - is it expected that when I run `nvm list` the result is:

```
->       system
iojs -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> N/A) (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
```

?

where version is `N/A`
and when I run `node --version` I see `v14.8.0`

what is proper way to reach my goal using **Homebrew**?

Comment: You can't with homebrew. Use [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) - I promise you'll never use homebrew to install node again. Once nvm is installed, you can switch between any version of node in a matter of seconds. If you've installed node with homebrew and nvm, remove the homebrew version to reduce confusion (trust me). With nvm, you will need to install every version you want with `nvm install 14`, etc

Comment: is there way to not uninstall `node` formula and keep proper behavior while switching via `nvm`? Which confusion you mean to reduce?

Comment: For example, you're already "confused" because you think `nvm list` should somehow recognize that 14 is installed somewhere on your system. nvm and homebrew are separate, and they both muck with your PATH, and it muddy's the water on "where is my node installed". I recommend NEVER using homebrew to install node - there are too many versions to support. Uninstall the homebrew one and only use nvm... again, trust me.

Comment: Got it, thx for itemized reply. I trust you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr - Uninstall the homebrew version, use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). Don't use homebrew to install node... ever.

I used both homebrew and nvm to install node years ago because I had some attachment to the idea that homebrew should be used whenever possible (a lot of articles recommend it, it's highly adopted in the mac community, I used it for installing lots of other software). I constantly had issues with certain terminals/tasks/scripts/etc using the wrong version of node. Don't be like me - homebrew is just a tool... a great tool... but it's not very good at installing multiple versions of a single piece of software and allowing easy switching between versions. NVM is very good at that. Use the tool for the job.